# Saving the original state of a class in javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a class

```
class Apple {
    constructor(color){
        this.state = {
            color: color
        }
    }

    getState(){
        return this.state;
    }

    setState(state){
        this.state = state;
    }

    turnGreen(){
        this.state.color = "Green";
    }
}
```

and if i do

```
let apple = new Apple("Red");

const originalState = apple.getState();

apple.turnGreen();             
console.log(apple.getState());   //{color: 'Green'}

apple.setState(originalState);
console.log(apple.getState());   //{color: 'Green'}
```

How come `const originalState` gets changed to 'Green' as well?
And is there any way to save the original state of the apple?
Thanks in advance

Comment: object has same reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language might help i guess

Comment: Easy fix: `const originalState = { ...apple.getState() };`